# Веса вершин рендерятся неверно в OpenGL

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

Так выглядят веса в моем приложении
[image: Так выглядят веса в моем приложении]

Так веса выглядят в Blender
[image: Так веса выглядят в Blender]

Можно заметить, что мой куб имеет зеленые точки внизу, а в Blender — нет. Я хочу понять, в чем проблема с моими весами, может быть проблема с тем, как я храню свои данные. Помогите пожалуйста найти ошибку!

Ниже я приведу некоторые обязательные части кода и ссылку на весь проект, чтобы можно было четко понять и воспроизвести проблему.

Ссылка: https://github.com/theoldestsc/PyrhonScratch

Обязательные части кода:

Вот так я загружаю Mesh (у меня есть класс Model, который содержит vector<Mesh>, и у меня есть отдельный vector<Vertex> для каждого Mesh)

```
Mesh Model::processMesh(aiMesh *mesh, const aiScene *scene)
{
    std::vector<Vertex> vertices;
    std::vector<unsigned int> indices;
    std::vector<Texture> textures;

    for(unsigned int vIdx = 0; vIdx < mesh->mNumVertices; vIdx++)
    {
        Vertex vertex;
        QVector3D vector;
        
        vector.setX(mesh->mVertices[vIdx].x);
        vector.setY(mesh->mVertices[vIdx].y);
        vector.setZ(mesh->mVertices[vIdx].z);
        vertex.position = vector;
        
        if (mesh->HasNormals())
        {
            vector.setX(mesh->mNormals[vIdx].x);
            vector.setY(mesh->mNormals[vIdx].y);
            vector.setZ(mesh->mNormals[vIdx].z);
            vertex.normal = vector;
        }
        if(mesh->mTextureCoords[0]) // does the mesh contain texture coordinates?
        {
            QVector2D vec;
            vec.setX(mesh->mTextureCoords[0][vIdx].x);
            vec.setY(mesh->mTextureCoords[0][vIdx].y);
            vertex.texcoord = vec;
        }
        else
            vertex.texcoord = QVector2D(0.0f, 0.0f);

        vertices.push_back(vertex);
    }

    for(unsigned int fIdx = 0; fIdx < mesh->mNumFaces; fIdx++)
    {
        aiFace face = mesh->mFaces[fIdx];
        for(unsigned int j = 0; j < face.mNumIndices; j++)
        {
            indices.push_back(face.mIndices[j]);
        }
    }

    if(mesh->mMaterialIndex >= 0)
    {
        aiMaterial *material = scene->mMaterials[mesh->mMaterialIndex];
        std::vector<Texture> diffuseMaps = loadMaterialTextures(material, aiTextureType_DIFFUSE, "texture_diffuse");
        textures.insert(textures.end(), diffuseMaps.begin(), diffuseMaps.end());
        std::vector<Texture> specularMaps = loadMaterialTextures(material, aiTextureType_SPECULAR, "texture_specular");
        textures.insert(textures.end(), specularMaps.begin(), specularMaps.end());
    }
    //TODO:Print status of mesh loading(Which mesh, path, number, sizes, bones)
    if(mesh->HasBones())
    {

        qDebug() << "Bones processing ...";
        for(int boneIndex = 0; boneIndex < mesh->mNumBones; ++boneIndex)
        {
            auto bone = mesh->mBones[boneIndex];

            std::string name = bone->mName.C_Str();
            int index = -1;
            if (boneIndexMap.find(name) == boneIndexMap.end()) {
                index = bones.size();
                Bone newBone;
                newBone.name = name;
                newBone.offsetMatrix = aiToQt(bone->mOffsetMatrix);
                bones.push_back(newBone);
                boneIndexMap[name] = index;
            } else {
                index = boneIndexMap[name];
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < bone->mNumWeights; ++i)
            {
                auto weightInfo = bone->mWeights[i];
                auto vertexId = weightInfo.mVertexId;
                auto weight = weightInfo.mWeight;

                for(int k = 0; k < WEIGHTS_PER_VERTEX; ++k)
                {
                    if(vertices.at(vertexId).weight[k] == 0.0)
                    {
                        vertices.at(vertexId).id[k] = index;
                        vertices.at(vertexId).weight[k] = weight;
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
        }

    }
    qDebug() << vertices.size() << " " << mesh->mNumFaces << " Bones data: " << boneIndexMap.size() << " " << bones.size() << "\n";
    return Mesh(vertices, indices, textures, bones);
}
```

Вот так я отправляю данные в OpenGL

```
void Mesh::setupMesh()
{
    auto functions = QOpenGLContext::currentContext()->functions();
    auto extraFunctions = QOpenGLContext::currentContext()->extraFunctions();
    
    VAO = std::shared_ptr<QOpenGLVertexArrayObject>(new QOpenGLVertexArrayObject());
    VBO = std::shared_ptr<QOpenGLBuffer>(new QOpenGLBuffer(QOpenGLBuffer::VertexBuffer));
    EBO = std::shared_ptr<QOpenGLBuffer>(new QOpenGLBuffer(QOpenGLBuffer::IndexBuffer));

    VAO->create();
    VBO->create();
    EBO->create();

    VAO->bind();

    VBO->setUsagePattern(QOpenGLBuffer::StaticDraw);
    EBO->setUsagePattern(QOpenGLBuffer::StaticDraw);
    VBO->bind();
    VBO->allocate(vertices.data(), vertices.size() * sizeof(Vertex));
    EBO->bind();
    EBO->allocate(indices.data(), indices.size() * sizeof(unsigned int));
    
    functions->glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    functions->glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)0);
    
    functions->glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    functions->glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex),
                                    (void*)offsetof(Vertex, normal));

    functions->glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    functions->glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), 
                                    (void*)offsetof(Vertex, texcoord));
    
    functions->glEnableVertexAttribArray(3);
    functions->glVertexAttribPointer(3, WEIGHTS_PER_VERTEX, GL_FLOAT, GL_TRUE, sizeof(Vertex), 
                                    (void*)offsetof(Vertex, weight));

    functions->glEnableVertexAttribArray(4);
    functions->glVertexAttribPointer(4, WEIGHTS_PER_VERTEX, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), 
                                    (void*)offsetof(Vertex, id));
                                    
    extraFunctions->glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

В структуре Vertex я храню 4 веса для каждой вершины, затем отправляю вектор этих вершин в OpenGL.

```
#define WEIGHTS_PER_VERTEX  4
struct Vertex
{
    QVector3D position;
    QVector2D texcoord;
    QVector3D normal;

    float weight[WEIGHTS_PER_VERTEX] = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};
    unsigned int id[WEIGHTS_PER_VERTEX] = {0, 0, 0, 0};

};
```

Структура Bone

```
struct Bone {
    std::string name; //Only this field is used
    int parentIndex;

    QMatrix4x4 offsetMatrix; //Only this field is used
    QMatrix4x4 finalTransform;
};
```

Мой vertex shader:

```
#version 440

const int MAX_BONES = 100;

layout (location = 0) in vec3 vertex_position;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 vertex_normal;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 vertex_texcoord;



layout (location = 3) in vec4 weights;
layout (location = 4) in ivec4 s_vIDs;


uniform mat4 ModelMatrix;
uniform mat4 ViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 ProjectionMatrix;

uniform mat4 gBones[MAX_BONES];

out vec2 TexCoords;
out vec4 we;
out vec4 id;
out vec3 interpolatedNormal;

void main()
{
    TexCoords = vertex_texcoord;

    vec4 totalPosition = vec4(0.0f);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++)
    {
        if(s_vIDs[i] == -1) 
            continue;
        if(s_vIDs[i] >= MAX_BONES) 
        {
            totalPosition = vec4(vertex_position, 1.0f);
            break;
        }
        vec4 localPosition = gBones[s_vIDs[i]] * vec4(vertex_position, 1.0f);
        totalPosition += localPosition * weights[i];
    }
    
    interpolatedNormal = normalize(mat3(transpose(inverse(ModelMatrix))) * vertex_normal);

    mat4 viewModel = ViewMatrix * ModelMatrix;
    gl_Position = ProjectionMatrix * viewModel * totalPosition;
    we = weights;
    id = s_vIDs;

}
```

Мой fragment shader:

```
#version 440
out vec4 FragColor;
in vec4 we;
in vec4 id;
in vec3 interpolatedNormal;
in vec2 TexCoords;

struct Material {
    sampler2D texture_diffuse1;
};

uniform Material material;

void main()
{    
    FragColor = we;
}
```

Просто хочу быть уверен, что моя анимация в будущем будет работать правильно, поэтому я хочу исправить эту ошибку, пока мой  код не станет больше. Может быть проблема с моим пониманием того, как Blender и OpenGL визуализируют данные весов
В общем, я бы хотел достичь аналогичного результата с Blender, чтобы в дальнейшем было проще проверять работу программы

Comment: *"ссылку на весь проект, чтобы можно было четко понять и воспроизвести проблему"* - вместо этого следовало локализовать проблему и составить [mcve]. Если проблема в неправильной загрузке модели, то не нужен код рисования, а если в неправильном рисовании, то не нужен код загрузки модели. И qt выпилите. Но вообще корректный импорт чего-то из блендера - задача нетривиальная.

Comment: @user7860670 Это обычная модель в формате .dae, не понимаю, почему она нетривиальная. Blender визуализирует ее так, OpenGL этак. QT используется вместо GLFW или GLUT.

Comment: @user7860670 Сама модель загружается верно, и там и там куб, проблема где-то в загрузке весов и их отображении, код чего я и привел.  Минимальный воспроизводимый пример положить сюда сложно(Ну конечно можно), ведь вы просите меня просто распаковать все мои классы. Проект совсем небольшой, но тут просматривать его будет не особо удобно, потому дал ссылку на github.

Comment: *(Ну конечно можно)* - не можно, а нужно, так как иначе вопрос является офтопиком на этом сайте.